# Pass and filter items by TimeStamp in Firestore for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pass today's date in Firestore `Timestamp` in my app. I am getting the today's date like this

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy"
let result = formatter.string(from: date)
print("Today date is \(result)")
let startDate = result + " " + "07:00:00"
let endDate = result + " " + "23:00:00"
```

I have to pass the today's date from morning 7 am to 23:00 pm and I stored this dates in `startDate` and `endDate`. Now I am passing these timing in `Firestore` query like this:-

```
self.db.collection("Locations").whereField("userid", isEqualTo: "\(selectedUserID)").whereField("createddatetime", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "\(startDate)").whereField("createddatetime", isLessThanOrEqualTo: "\(endDate)").getDocuments()
```

but I am getting no results in my snapshot. How can I do this. Please help?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need:

1) Convert String -> Date

2) Convert Date -> Timestamp (FIRTimestamp)

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss"

let startTime: Date = formatter.date(from: startDate) ?? Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
let startTimestamp: Timestamp = Timestamp(date: startTime)

let endTime: Date = formatter.date(from: endDate) ?? Date()
let endTimestamp: Timestamp = Timestamp(date: endTime)
```

3) Change func to:

```
self.db.collection("Locations")
        .whereField("userid", isEqualTo: "\(selectedUserID)")
        .whereField("createddatetime", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startTimestamp)
        .whereField("createddatetime", isLessThanOrEqualTo: endTimestamp)
        .getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in

        ...

}
```