# Query after todays date firestore - Swift

Tags: swift, date, google-cloud-firestore

I basically want to query todays date (plus or minus 12 hours) or I wouldn't mind querying from today's date onward such as `.whereField("Date" isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Date())` The only problem is that i've used up my "greater-than" fetch. Is there a work around to this?

```
 let db = Firestore.firestore()

    let ref = db.collection("Posts")
        .whereField("myCoordinates", isGreaterThan: SWCorner)
        .whereField("myCoordinates", isLessThan: NECorner)
        .whereField("Date()", isGreaterThan: Date())
```

Comment: What means "today: It's between "midnight and midnight", the start of the day, and the end of the day. So it's greater than start and less than end, no?  https://medium.com/@karsonbraaten/swift-and-firestore-query-for-fields-with-todays-date-d07bea56c79d https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456953/pass-and-filter-items-by-timestamp-in-firestore-for-swift etc.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions Larme, but it still doesn't fix my problem because I have already used up my ">" & "<" fetches. With firebase you can only do this once and i chose to use it on "my coordinates". I appreciate the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can tell from the error message, this specific type of query isn't possible.  What you can do instead is store the date as something more generalized, such as YYYYMMDD, then query for the specific dates that could match, given the current time.  You would use an ["in" query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any), for example:

```
.whereField("date", in: ["x", "y"])
```

where x and y are the formatted dates for posts that you're interested in.  You could then filter out the results on the client that are outside the bounds you want.

In any case, you will need different field data to work with in order to avoid have multiple range queries.